# Debugging Error with JSON de - serialization

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I try to download data from my link and deserialize it. I tried to do this with JSON.Net, but i've got some error. I've created a struct which copies the struct of JSON data in my link. Help me.
`JsonUserObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonUserObject>(json);` - this throws System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.
Also, it doesn't let me debug it, it crashes as the program loads, if i put a breakpoint anywhere it doesn't hit it, it just errors right away.

That's all my code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PhoneAppChanging
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        //private string json;        
        // Конструктор
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)            
            { return; }
            string json = e.Result;
            try
            {
                JsonUserObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonUserObject>(json);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://barnistan.belinski.biz/en/barn-i-stan/export/cats"));
        }
    }
}
```

The code of JsonUserObject struct:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

[JsonObject]
public struct JsonUserObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string status
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Data[] data
    { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public struct Data
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string id
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string title
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string count
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string subcount
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string cat_img
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Childs[] Childs
    { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public struct Childs
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string id
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string title
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string count
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string subcount
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string cat_img
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]    
    public smallChilds[] childs
    { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public struct smallChilds
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string id
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string title
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string count
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string subcount
    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string cat_img
    { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for help for everyone.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Smt like this http://gyazo.com/4732b0c42871a0b6830832676c39e3d8

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:

Comment: That's not the message. That's the exception. You can either read it off the debugger or wrap your call in a try/catch block and get e.Message in your code.

Comment: I tried to catch exception. I've had "MithingMethodException" and this "Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30AD4FE6B2A6AEED'"

Comment: Did you add JSON.Net via Nuget to your project?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'd solved my problem with using DataContractSerializer.